# query string syntax in ajax function in php to get results from the redirected page

Tags: php, ajax, redirect, query-string

```
<script>
function serviceAdd(rateid,vendorid,countrycode,destination,routetype,rate)
{
alert(rateid+vendorid+countrycode+destination+routetype+rate);  
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","check_servicing.php?rate_id="+rateid+"&vendor_id="+vendorid+"&countrycode_id="+countrycode+"&destination_id="+destination+"&routetype_id="+routetype+"&rate="+rate+"",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

This is the ajax function. Its values are fetched but not redirecting.
This page is not redirecting to check_servicing.php.
Please Help!!

Comment: Why should it redirect? You do realize this is AJAX, right?

Comment: Set  **window.location** dude.

Comment: actually its not executing the code on check_servicing.php.

Comment: Please is anyone interested in replying? I need it urgently!!